# Bypassing SSL Certificate Validation on DotNet Core Service Stack

Tags: c#, linux, servicestack, .net-core

I know that `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` no longer exists in .Net Core and is instead replaced with:

```
using(var handler = new System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler())
{
    using (var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(handler))
    {
        handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (request, cert, chain, errors) =>
        {
            return true;
        };

    }
}
```

However we are currently using the `ServiceStack.Core` library which, as far as I can see, does not expose either a property like this or the handler itself.

How would I tell a ServiceStack client to bypass ssl validation in this code?

```
using(var client = new JsonServiceClient("https://www.google.com"))
{
    var response = client.Get("/results");
}
```

If there is a way, would this work the same on both Windows and Linux?

Comment: *"Bypassing SSL Certificate Validation..."* - Sounds awful. It moves your app into the realm of [The most dangerous code in the world: validating SSL certificates in non-browser software](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/abstracts/ssl-client-bugs.html). Perhaps you should rephrase it as *"How to perform custom validation ..."*, and then perform checks that make sense for your app.

Comment: @jww "The most dangerous code in the world" sounds awfully hyperbolic to me, especially without context.  What if you're writing a tool accessing an internal service with a self signed cert?

Comment: If you have a self signed certificate, then you can validate it. There's no need to forgo or avoid validation. You can even skip the certificate validation and jump into public key pinning. In the case of pinning, the certificate is just a presentation detail, and all you need is the host's public key to identify it. I'm thinking you may be asking the wrong question, but I don't know enough to say for sure. Maybe you should step back, and ask questions like how to use a self-signed certificate with your service.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`JsonServiceClient` is built on .NET `HttpWebRequest` which has been rewritten in .NET Core as a [wrapper over HttpClient](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Requests/src/System/Net/HttpWebRequest.cs) so we'd generally recommend for .NET Core to avoid this overhead (which is much slower than .NET 4.5) and switch to using [JsonHttpClient in ServiceStack.HttpClient](http://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-client) instead as it uses `HttpClient` directly and where you can inject your own `HttpClientHandler` with:

```
var client = new JsonHttpClient(baseUrl)
{
    HttpMessageHandler = new HttpClientHandler
    {
        UseCookies = true,
        AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate,
        ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (req,cert,chain,errors) => true
    }
};
```

Note it's recommended to [reuse HttpClient instances](https://skimming.net/why-you-should-reuse-httpclient-instances/) so you should try to reuse HttpClient instances when possible and avoid disposing them.