# Disabling certificate validation for identityserver4

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, identityserver4

I have IdentityServer4 and MVC core app and React as clients. On localhost everything works just fine, but as soon as i'm trying to deploy everything in docker ubuntu i face troubles with the sertificate

`System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch, RemoteCertificateChainErrors`.

React app works perfect, but mvc can't obtain configuration from `.well-known/opendid-configuration`. I know that this troubles are caused by the self-signed sertificate. I've tried to create certificate using `dotnet dev-certs https -ep...`. But it didn't work. So now i want to disable certificate checking. How can i do this as i've tried to disable metadata using `config.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;`? I also know that i can disable CertificateValidation by using

`ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;`

but i don't know how to innvoke this delegate?

And Maybe there are any other possible ways of solving this issue?

Comment: Something like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66549004/1752270) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a proper signing certificate using [openssl](https://www.openssl.org/):

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365

openssl pkcs12 -export -out keyStore.p12 -inkey key.pem -in cert.pem
```